# Promise not firing on all functions

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I'm trying to use an API built with callback functions using promises.

To test it, I've created this three functions:

```
this.functionResolve = (data) => console.log('resolved: ' + data)
this.functionError = (data) => console.log('error: ' + data)
this.functionSucess = (data) => console.log('success: ' + data)
```

If using the normal callback functions, everything works fine and I get two logs. (resolve and error/success depending on the cardBin informed)

`PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
    cardBin: "000000",
    complete: this.functionResolve,
    success: this.functionSucess,
    error: this.functionError
});`

To convert this to promise, I ended up with this:

```
this.promisifyCallback = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, _success, _error) => {
        PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
            cardBin: "000000",
            complete: resolve,
            success: _success,
            error: _error
        });
    });
}
```

When I call `this.promisifyCallback().then(this.functionResolve, this.functionSucess, this.functionError)` only the resolve log appears.

In case anybody wants to check, the PagSeguroDirectPayment object is available at: [PagSeguro API](https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js)

Comment: Promiuses have two callbacks, not three.  There is no notion of a separate `success` callback.

Comment: You need to call resolve or reject to return the data as a thenable. Then use .then to process it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise executor function (the callback you pass `new Promise`) only receives **two** arguments, not three: `resolve` (to resolve the project) and `reject` (to reject it). *(You can call them anything you want; those are common names to use.)*

That means with your current code:

- You'll resolve when the request is complete, whether it worked or not, because of `success: resolve`
- You'll reject when the request succeeds (because of `success: _success`) (unless that API calls the `complete` handler first; a promise can only be resolved or rejected once)
- Your `_error` parameter will always be `undefined`

Instead:

```
this.promisifyCallback = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
            cardBin: "035138",
            //complete: ,
            success: resolve,
            error: reject
        });
    });
}
```

When *consuming* the promise, you can get the `complete` behavior by using `.finally` (in up-to-date environments, or with a polyfill — `finally` was added fairly recently).

> When I call `this.promisifyCallback().then(this.functionResolve, this.functionSucess, this.functionError)` only the resolve log appears.

You'd use it like this:

```
this.promisifyCallback()
    .then(this.functionSucess, this.functionError)
    .finally(this.functionResolve); // See ¹
```

or

```
this.promisifyCallback()
    .then(this.functionSucess)
    .catch(this.functionError)
    .finally(this.functionResolve); // See ¹
```

---

¹ "Resolve" in Promise-language means "complete successfully" ("fulfill" is also sometimes used). "Reject" means fail. "Settle" means resolve or reject.